# Trigonometric equation $\sin v = -1/\sqrt{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve the following: $$\sin(v) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

My attempt:

$$-\sin(v) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$\sin(-v) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$v_1 = -\frac{\pi}{4} - 2\pi n $$

$$v_2 = -\pi + \frac{\pi}{4} - 2\pi n = \frac{-3\pi}{4} - 2\pi n$$

$v_1 $ is correct, but $v_2 $ should apparently be $ \frac{5\pi}{4} + 2\pi n$

why?

Comment: Because they're actually the same...

Comment: You can produce $\sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, \cot x$ by writing \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, \cot x, respectively, in math mode.

Comment: @Asydot ooh okay, I guess I just dont see it
N.F.Taussig Aah, thanks :)

Comment: It's the same, because $n$ is an arbitrary integer... it's not the same for the same $n$ in both cases, but the values the expressions visit for all integer $n$ are the same. Just the enumeration is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $$-\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi = \frac{5\pi}{4}$$  If you substitute $-m - 1$ for $n$ in the expression $$-\frac{3\pi}{4} - 2\pi n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$ you obtain $$-\frac{3\pi}{4} - 2\pi(-m - 1) = -\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi m + 2\pi = \frac{5\pi}{4} + 2\pi m$$
where $m = -n - 1 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Rotation for angle $v$ ends in  quadrants 3 and 4. The tip of radius vector points in the directions of the Southwest and  Southeast.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin x=-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}=-\sin\dfrac\pi4=\sin\left(-\dfrac\pi4\right)$$
as $\sin(-A)=-\sin A$
$$\implies x=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(-\dfrac\pi4\right)$$ where $n$ is any integer